# Diferença entre datas em varias linhas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Existe alguma forma de fazer um DATEDIFF/LEAD/LAG no SQL Server para calcular a diferença entre datas levando em consideração a data do registro anterior/próximo.

**SELECT**

```
SELECT NUM, CLIENTE, EMISSAO
  FROM PEDIDOS
 WHERE CLIENTE = '06.028'
 ORDER BY EMISSAO DESC
```

**Resultado**

```
NUM     CLIENTE EMISSAO
35890H  06.028  20160226
y35888  06.028  20160225
y33449  06.028  20160122
y33046  06.028  20160111
y28763  06.028  20151125
AS9816  06.028  20151118
```

**Resultado Esperado:**

```
ROW CODIGO EMISSAO  TEMPO
1   06.028 20160226 5     -=> Utiliza o GETDATE() ou Deixa Zerado (0)
2   06.028 20141030 484   -=> Utiliza a data da linha 1
3   06.028 20141030 0     -=> Utiliza a data da linha 2
4   06.028 20140930 30    -=> Utiliza a data da linha 3
5   06.028 20140612 145   -=> Utiliza a data da linha 4
6   05.127 20160102 29    -=> Utiliza o GETDATE() ou Deixa Zerado (0)
7   05.127 20151225  9    -=> Utiliza a data da linha 6
8   05.127 20151205 20    -=> Utiliza a data da linha 7
```

*Obs: a coluna **ROW** é apenas para exibir a linha a qual estou me referenciando na descrição (-=>) ao lado.*

Ao mudar o cliente, deixa de utilizar a data do cliente anterior e começa tudo de novo.

Comment: qual campo é DATE?

Comment: EMISSAO no formato YYYYMMDD

Comment: Deu certo?.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer da seguinte forma

```
declare @Tabela1 table
(
   ROW int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- Se sua tabela tive um campo IDENTITY(1,1) use ele 
   NUM varchar(10) null,
   CLIENTE varchar(10),
   EMISSAO date
)

insert into @Tabela1 (CLIENTE,EMISSAO ) values -- (NUM, CLIENTE,EMISSAO ) values -- aqui você faz o insert com o select da sua tabela 
--SELECT NUM, CLIENTE, EMISSAO
--  FROM PEDIDOS
-- WHERE CLIENTE = '06.028'
-- ORDER BY EMISSAO DESC

('06.028', '20160226'  ), 
('06.028', '20141030'   ), 
('06.028', '20141030'   ), 
('06.028', '20141030'  ), 
( '06.028', '20140612'  ), 
('05.127', '20160102'   ),  
('05.127', '20151225'  ),   
('05.127', '20151220'  ) ,
('05.127', '20151220'   ) ,
('05.127', '20151218'   ) ,
('05.127', '20151213'  ) 

select 
 tb.NUM, tb.CLIENTE, tb.EMISSAO,
case    
    when tb.CLIENTE = prev.CLIENTE then DATEDIFF (DAY , tb.EMISSAO, prev.EMISSAO) else 0 end TEMPO
 from @Tabela1 tb
join @Tabela1 prev 
ON prev.ROW = tb.ROW - 1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O Exemplo que informei acima é o resultado esperado, e não a tabela que eu já tenho... pois preciso exatamente do campo tempo entre as duas datas.

Comment: Em dias? ......

Comment: Pode passar o select da tabela normal ? só para sabe como esta seus dados

Comment: Sim, em dias, alterei a descrição da pergunta com mais detalhes, SELECT, RESULTADO e RESULTADO ESPERADO.

Comment: Não mudou muita coisa... Basta criar uma tabela temp para isso.

Answer (score 0):

O resultado esperado está em ordem decrescente de data e a coluna TEMPO é a diferença, em dias, entre a linha atual e a linha anterior.

Eis a sugestão usando LAG e DATEDIFF, conforme mencionado no enunciado da questão:

```
-- código #1
set dateformat ymd;

with PARcliente as (
SELECT NUM, CLIENTE, EMISSAO,
       proxEMISSAO= lag (EMISSAO) over (partition by CLIENTE order by EMISSAO desc)
  from PEDIDOS
)
SELECT CLIENTE, EMISSAO, 
       datediff (day, EMISSAO, proxEMISSAO) as TEMPO
  from PARcliente
  order by CLIENTE, EMISSAO desc;
```

Pela amostra de dados a coluna EMISSAO contém data mas está armazenada como texto, provavelmente em coluna char(8). Para evitar erros de conversão implícita foi configurado o `dateformat` para ymd; detalhes no artigo [Os perigos da conversão automática de tipos de dados](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/os-perigos-da-conversao-implicita-1/).

Answer (score -1):

você pode fazer isto utilizando uma CTE:

```
DECLARE @PEDIDOS AS TABLE(
    NUM INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    CLIENTE VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    EMISSAO DATE NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @PEDIDOS VALUES
('06.028', '2016-02-26'),
('06.028', '2014-10-30'),
('06.028', '2014-10-30'),
('06.028', '2014-09-30'),
('06.028', '2014-06-12'),
('05.127', '2016-01-02'),
('05.127', '2015-12-25'),
('05.127', '2015-12-05');

WITH CTE_ROOT AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTE ORDER BY EMISSAO DESC) AS ORDEM,
        NUM, 
        CLIENTE, 
        EMISSAO
    FROM @PEDIDOS
), CTE_LOOP AS (
    SELECT 
        CTE_ROOT.ORDEM,
        CTE_ROOT.NUM, 
        CTE_ROOT.CLIENTE, 
        CTE_ROOT.EMISSAO,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, CTE_ROOT.EMISSAO, SYSDATETIME()) AS TEMPO
    FROM CTE_ROOT
    WHERE CTE_ROOT.ORDEM = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CTE_ROOT.ORDEM,
        CTE_ROOT.NUM, 
        CTE_ROOT.CLIENTE, 
        CTE_ROOT.EMISSAO,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, CTE_ROOT.EMISSAO, CTE_LOOP.EMISSAO) AS TEMPO
    FROM CTE_LOOP
    JOIN CTE_ROOT ON CTE_LOOP.CLIENTE = CTE_ROOT.CLIENTE
    WHERE CTE_LOOP.ORDEM + 1 = CTE_ROOT.ORDEM
)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE_LOOP
ORDER BY CLIENTE, ORDEM
```